# Full row select on GridView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with some column.First column is a template field:

```
...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                        NavigateUrl='<%# "~/mail/showMail.aspx?q="+Eval("id") %>'>Select</asp:HyperLink>
           </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
```

I want use full row select instead of this above TemplateField. I use this code:

```
protected void grdList_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
                this.Page.ClientScript.
               GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        }
}
```

But not work.

How use hyperlink instead of "Select$", like this:

```
ClientScript.
               GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdList, "~/mail/showMail.aspx?q=Eval(\"id\")" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

I use a boundField instead of template field like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" />
```

and use this event:

```
protected void grdList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        GridViewRow SelectedRow = grdList.SelectedRow;
        string id = SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/Mail/ShowMail.aspx?q=" + id);
}

protected void grdList_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
            this.Page.ClientScript.
           GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdList, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about full row select?